# Making data trend using python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make data trending using python for a dataframe for eg my raw data in csv is below format

```
Date TCH_Nom TCH_Denom SD_Nom SD_Denom  

1/08/2018 42  58 4 21  
2/08/2018 67 100 12 120  
3/08/2018 23 451 9 34
```

Output should be

```
KPI        1/08/2018 2/08/2018 3/08/2018  
TCH_Nom     42         67        23  
TCH_Denom   58         100       451  
SD_Nom       4         12         9  
SD_Denom     21        120       34
```

Comment: Your desired output has nothing to do with data *trends*. You seem to want the *transpose* of your data. Also -- where did `KPI` rather than `Date` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = '''Date TCH_Nom TCH_Denom SD_Nom SD_Denom

1/08/2018 42 58 4 21
2/08/2018 67 100 12 120
3/08/2018 23 451 9 34'''
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt),sep = '\s+')
```

As pointed out in comment:

```
df.set_index('Date',inplace = True) # set index to Date column
df.T
```

which gives this outcome:

```
Date    1/08/2018   2/08/2018   3/08/2018
TCH_Nom 42  67  23
TCH_Denom   58  100 451
SD_Nom  4   12  9
SD_Denom    21  120 34
```